# Regex to replace substring occurrences *only* when they are enclosed between begin / end brackets

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, string-substitution

regex problem in ruby, and for some reason, I need this in **one line in gsub method** of ruby

Suppose the input `sample` string variable is multi line string like below

```
begin1 item abc item abc item 
extra end1
begin2 item abc item abc extra end2
begin1 item abc item abc extra end1
```

The rule is to change all `item` which inside block `begin1` and `end1` into `love`, it may across multi lines

After replace, the output `sample` should be

```
begin1 love abc love abc love 
extra end1
begin2 item abc item abc extra end2
begin1 love abc love abc love end1
```

The solution is something like this

```
puts sample.gsub!(/(begin1.*)item*(.*end1)/m,'\1love\2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one: `sample.gsub!(/item(?=((?!begin1).)*end1)/m, 'love')`?

And, to make the regex a little bit less magic:

```
/ 
  item              
  (?=               # look-ahead assertion
    (               
      (?!begin1)    # negative look-ahead assertion
      .             # any character that is not part of the 'begin1' sequence
    )*              # there's no 'begin1' after 'item' and before 'end1'
    end1            # there is 'end1' after 'item'
  )
/mx                 # /m - for multiline strings, x - for comments
```

(Note, that it will work correctly only if your 'markup' is 'correct' - e.g. there is no trailing ends or leading begins, no nesting blocks)

Also, I can't help to say that regexes is poor tool for such a task. Complex regular expressions are too incomprehensible and too unmaintainable, they are like black magic - you never know when they're gonna crash :)

Comment: So magic, and it works exactly what I want.

And it works fine for small input, when it goes big, it reports

    `Stack overflow in regexp matcher`

Comment: the answer is good enough, `stack overflow` is related with ruby 1.8.7 only, solution works fine in 1.9.

thank alexis. see real script https://github.com/larrycai/sdcamp/commit/923237e5c

Comment: I tested it with 100M long string - it took pair minutes to finish, but there was no 'stack overflow' in 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean with the input part of your question, so I'm a bit confused but I think you're using the `gsub` method the wrong way.  Try this:

```
> string = 'begin1 item abc item abc item'
=> "begin1 item abc item abc item"
> string.gsub(/item/, 'love')
=> "begin1 love abc love abc love"
```

It's a simple regular expression substitution method.  [Read the docs for more details on how to use it](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub).  I think you may be making it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I update the question.

the input is the multi line string, and change `item` between `begin1` and `end1` to `love` in one line